# How to identify if RMM4 hardware module is installed

Tags: linux, remote

I'm running a Debian distribution with ipmiutil on one of my remote servers but I'm not sure if an RMM4(Remote Management Module) hardware is installed on this server. Currently I don't have visibility on the hardware and it's interfaces, is it possible to know if an RMM4 Intel module is installed on this server from the Debian OS command line?

Comment: I take it you've tried `lsmod|grep rmm`?

Comment: I tried this on a server with RMM4 and the other that I'm not sure of, both are not returning anything for this command.

Comment: You say that one of those servers has RMM4 (whatever that means).  How are you sure of this?

Comment: Hang on, I think we may be talking at cross-purposes.  When you say "*is RMM4 module installed*", are you talking about a software (kernel) module, or a piece of hardware?

Comment: It's the RMM4 piece of hardware. The server that has the RMM4, I installed it myself, I connected the RMM4 port to the network, configured it and I'm managing it remotely but the other server is in another site that I never had visibility over it so I'm not sure if it has the RMM4 module.

Comment: Sorry, my bad; I've clarified the question, but can't help with an answer.  I suspect it will need someone else with similar hardware to contribute.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that if on the local host "ipmitool lan print X" where X is 1 to 3 all work, you have a RMM module on top of the standard mobo bmc. Otherwise you only see channel 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a raw query to get the information you need:

```
# ipmitool raw 0x30 0x71 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x00
 11 02
```

The "02" in the response signifies RMM4 while "01" would indicate the presence of an RMM3 module. As for the significance of the bytes in the raw query, "0x30" signifies "Intel General Application", "0x71" is the "Get Advanced Support Configuration" command, "0x00" means "Get parameter", "0x01" signifies test for presence while the last two bytes are unused.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ipmitool info` to get information about the installed BMC, which is part of the RMM4. (You may also need to `modprobe bmc` first.)

If it returns no information, then such a hardware module is not installed.

Comment: I don't think the BMC is part of the RMM4, in most cases BMC comes on the baseboard and accessed through the RMM4 if installed. I tried the "ipmiutil health" command(no info cmd) and I'm always getting results with BMC info even on a system without an RMM4:
server-without-RMM4:~ # ipmiutil health
ipmiutil ver 2.85
ihealth ver 2.85
BMC version       = 1.16, IPMI v2.0
BMC manufacturer  = 000157 (Intel), product = 005d (CG2200)
server-with-RMM4:~ # ipmiutil health
ipmiutil ver 2.85
ihealth ver 2.85
BMC version       = 1.16, IPMI v2.0
BMC manufacturer  = 000157 (Intel), product = 005d (CG2200)

Answer (score 0):

We recently ran into this issue.  I came up with a solution by cURLing through the BMC's Web GUI interface.

Some Presetup:

- Assign IPMI BMC IP Address/netmask via ipmitool.
- Assign a User/pw and enable user via ipmitool.
- Essentially you need to setup the BMC  to be able to login through the GUI..

Once that is done... Use this script below ... 
Edit the bmcUser && bmcPassword Variables to whatever username and password you used... and then execute the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

bmcIP=$(ipmitool lan print | grep "IP Address              : " | awk '{print $4}')

bmcUser="ipmiUserName"
bmcPassword="bmcPW"


# CHECK TO SEE IF BMC IP is UP

checkIP=$(ping -c1 -t1 $bmcIP && echo "up" || echo "down" )

if [[ "$checkIP" == *"up"* ]]; then

sessionID=$(curl "http://${bmcIP}/rpc/WEBSES/create.asp" -H "Origin: http://${bmcIP}" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36" -H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Accept: */*" -H "Referer: http://${bmcIP}/page/login.html"  -H "Connection: keep-alive" --data "WEBVAR_USERNAME=${bmcUser}&WEBVAR_PASSWORD=${bmcPassword}" --compressed  2>/dev/null |  grep SESSION_COOKIE  | awk -F\' '{print $4}')


curl "http://${bmcIP}/rpc/getrmm3status.asp" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8" -H "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Cache-Control: max-age=0" -H "Cookie: lang=EN; SessionCookie=${sessionID}; Username=${bmcUser}; lItem=0; test=1" -H "Connection: keep-alive" --compressed 2>/dev/null| grep  "'STATE' : 1" > /dev/null  && echo -e "RMM Installed\n\n" || echo -e "RMM NOT-Installed\n\n"

else

        echo -e "BMC IP is not accessible\n\n"
fi
```